# Javascript - Phonegap Unable to throw new Error from a function

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, error-handling, runtime-error

I am unable to throw errors from my phonegap application using the following lines of code:

```
var myBook = ['..an Array of sentences..', '...']

this.getIds = function(sentence){
    var index = myBook.indexOf(sentence);
    if(index == -1) throw new Error(sentence + ' does not appear in the book!');
    return index;
};

...
this.getIds('this is an invalid sentence');
...
```

Am I missing out something here? or am I looking at the wrong place for seeing the thrown error? I am expecting my thrown error in Safari's Web Inspector, but no error shows up there while testing on iOS simulator.

I also tried

```
throw 'this sentence does not appear in the book!';
```

No error so-far. Thanks for your time..

**RESOLVED:** This question is resolved now, and I verified throwing Errors. It appears that the problem was not related to Phonegap after all, it was a mere test condition fail on the if check.. I was so sure about the test condition, I did not even consider changing it and tryinh. Now, here's a bad debugging practice :) Thank you people for your interest.

Comment: Try to throw an Error before you call getIds. Does it work?

Comment: @Baidaly Hey thanks to your response I figured out my problem and got it working! It was fool of me not trying to throw Error outside the function. I thought it could be a phonegap limitation or something, and lost focus... The actual arrays I had were much different than the example I provided here. It was a mere test condition fail like:  myTestIndex > index. I changed it to myTestIndex >= index, and voila..